# g:select save to database selected item in grails

Tags: grails

I have tables: Products and Shop.(I generate controllers using grails generate-all) Shop hasmany products
I'm trying to do is List all the shops in  and save to database selected shop when creating a new product.
I listed all values using

```
<g:form controller="product" action="save" role="form">
    <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Product Name:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <g:textField name="productName" class="form-control" value="${product.productName}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Product Barcode</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <g:textField name="date expired" class="form-control" value="${product.productBarcode}"></g:textField>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Product Shop</label>
            <g:select class="selectpicker" name="products.id" from="${tr.com.netiket.lkkstoreapp.Shop.list()}" value="shop?.products.id" optionValue="shopName"></g:select>
        </div>
</g:form>
```

when i click create button it says

> Property [shop] of class [class tr.com.nur.storeapp.Product] cannot be null

Comment: I solved my problem. I writing here to help other. All I've done is add optionkey to g:select other way shop return null.    <g:select class="form-control" name="shop.id" from="${tr.com.lkkstoreapp.Shop.list()}" optionKey="id" value="product?.shop?.id" optionValue="shopName"></g:select>

Answer (score 0):

This bit doesn't look right:

`<g:select class="selectpicker" name="products.id" from="${tr.com.netiket.lkkstoreapp.Shop.list()}" value="shop?.products.id" optionValue="shopName"></g:select>`

The name should be the id of the Shop and the value should be the product's shop id, if present:

`<g:select class="selectpicker" name="shop.id" from="${tr.com.netiket.lkkstoreapp.Shop.list()}" value="${product?.shop?.id}" optionValue="shopName"></g:select>`

Comment: thanks @Gregg for answer. But this time it says;Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation Do you have any idea

Comment: You'd have to show your save method. I wonder if it is related or if you've uncovered another issue getting past this issue?

Comment: I posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Transactional
def save(Shop shop) {
    //println "in shop save"
    def currentUser=(User)springSecurityService.currentUser
    shop.user=currentUser
    shop.validate()
    if (!shop) {
        //println "I have no shop"
        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
        notFound()
        return
    }

    //if (shop.hasErrors()) {
     if (shop.save(flush:true)) {
       //println "shop has errors"
        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
        respond shop.errors, view:'create'
        shop.errors.allErrors
        return
    }

    //shop.save flush:true
    //println "shop has saved"

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'shop.label', default: 'Shop'), shop.id])
             //println "redirecting"
            redirect shop
        }
        '*' { respond shop, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

This is my save method. Actuaally I didint write anything here. Generate domain .

Comment: I have changed your answer and made it simpler where possible - basically  too many of the same things but lots of commented out printlns - you see to really uncover where you are in your code whilst developing you should try putting some test println statements in your if statements etc to ensure everything is work and you are hitting the right place

Comment: As a side note. Whilst SO has no issues with  the user answering own question.  This at the moment isn't the actual answer. So it may be worth deleting it and editing the actual question and adding the above to it. I hope you have resolved your issue. This comment is about good practise for future users who may refer to this question and your own reputation from getting negative scores